# EditForm in Blazor app have multiple submit buttons

Tags: html, razor, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I have a simple Blazor Editform where i have multiple buttons with different navigations & toast notifications. I have OnValidSubmit attached to Editform. Now the validations are working for all the buttons. I have added onclick() to trigger button functions but I want onclick to be triggered only if user has entered all the details. Hope I have explained well. Please let me know for additional input.

Current output for Forward or Next buttons are : if No values entered ->  Correct validation(asked to fill in details) -> forward notification displayed.

Expected output :
if No values entered ->  Correct validation(asked to fill in details).
if All values entered -> Correct validation -> forward notification displayed.

Here is some code:

```
 <EditForm EditContext="@editContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit"  @onreset="HandleReset">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <label>Role</label><br />
                    <InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="model.Role" class="form-control">
                        @foreach (var option in rdOptions)
                        {
                            <InputRadio Value="option" /> @option
                            <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
                        }
                    </InputRadioGroup>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.Role)" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col">
                    <label>Company Name</label>
                    <InputSelect id="txtCompanyName" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@model.CompanyName">
                        <option selected value="-1">-Select-</option>
                        <option value="CompanyName1">CompanyName1</option>
                        <option value="CompanyName2">CompanyName2</option>
                    </InputSelect>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => model.CompanyName)" />
                </div>
            </div>
         

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="text-left col-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
                <div class="text-right col-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@Forward">Forward</button>
                </div>
                <div class="text-right col-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@Review">Next</button>
                </div>
                <div class="text-right col-3">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
```

code section:

```
@code {
    private Model model = new Model();
    private EditContext editContext;
    List<Model> models = new();


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new EditContext(model);
    }

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        var modelJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
        JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", $"SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n{modelJson}");
        toastService.ShowSuccess("saved successfully!");
    }

    private void Forward()
    {
        toastService.ShowInfo("Forwarded!!");
    }

    private void Review()
    {
        toastService.ShowInfo("Review!!");
    }
    private void HandleReset()
    {
        model = new Model();
        editContext = new EditContext(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this server side or a web assembly please, @Shrey ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do validation manually in your button event handlers and then not use the `EditForm` `OnValidSubmit`, and set the button types to `button`.

```
...
if (editContext.Validate())
 go
else
 alert
...
```

FYI - The relevant bit of code from `EditForm` looks like this:

```
        private async Task HandleSubmitAsync()
        {
            Debug.Assert(_editContext != null);

            if (OnSubmit.HasDelegate)
            {
                // When using OnSubmit, the developer takes control of the validation lifecycle
                await OnSubmit.InvokeAsync(_editContext);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, the system implicitly runs validation on form submission
                var isValid = _editContext.Validate(); // This will likely become ValidateAsync later

                if (isValid && OnValidSubmit.HasDelegate)
                {
                    await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(_editContext);
                }

                if (!isValid && OnInvalidSubmit.HasDelegate)
                {
                    await OnInvalidSubmit.InvokeAsync(_editContext);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Except maybe for the Save button.

Comment: I will need validations for all the button but onclick should be working only if correct validation. Your answer helps a partof it. I have tried out something & its working. Let me post.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you will need to use JavaScript to check the inputs were filled or not and based on that you can disable or enable the submit button